# OpenSSL DTLS connection never establishes

Tags: c, sockets, openssl, dtls

I'm sorry for such a big block of code, but I'm so lost as to what is happening, I have no idea where the problem might be...

I am trying to get a VERY minimal dtls server going and I can't get the client and server to finish handshaking.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>

int generate_cookie(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int *cookie_len)
{
    cookie = "cookie";
    cookie_len = 5;

    return 1;
}

int verify_cookie(SSL *ssl, const unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int cookie_len)
{
    return 1;
}

int dtls_verify_callback (int ok, X509_STORE_CTX *ctx) {
    /* This function should ask the user
     * if he trusts the received certificate.
     * Here we always trust.
     */
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char buff[FILENAME_MAX];
    getcwd(buff, FILENAME_MAX);

    union {
        struct sockaddr_storage ss;
        struct sockaddr_in s4;
        struct sockaddr_in6 s6;
    } client_addr;

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    const int on = 1, off = 0;

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(client_addr));

    int res;

    SSL *ssl;
    BIO *bio;
    int sock;
    struct timeval timeout;

    SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLS_server_method());
    SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF);

    if(!SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "/home/matthew/CLionProjects/OpenSSL.Test/cmake-build-debug/certs/cert.crt", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    {
        perror("cert");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(!SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "/home/matthew/CLionProjects/OpenSSL.Test/cmake-build-debug/certs/key.key", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM))
    {
        perror("key");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE, dtls_verify_callback);
    SSL_CTX_set_read_ahead(ctx, 1);
    SSL_CTX_set_cookie_generate_cb(ctx, generate_cookie);
    SSL_CTX_set_cookie_verify_cb(ctx, &verify_cookie);

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(1114);

    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*) &on, (socklen_t) sizeof(on)) < 0)
    {
        perror("set reuse address");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (const char*) &on, (socklen_t) sizeof(on)) < 0)
    {
        perror("set reuse port");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(bind(sock, (const struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&client_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage));

    /* Create BIO */
    bio = BIO_new_dgram(sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);

    /* Set and activate timeouts */
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_RECV_TIMEOUT, 0, &timeout);

    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

    SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
    SSL_set_options(ssl, SSL_OP_COOKIE_EXCHANGE);

    if(!SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock))
    {
        perror("set fd");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

res = 0;
while(res <= 0)
{
    res = DTLSv1_listen(ssl, (BIO_ADDR *) &client_addr);
    if(res < 0)
    {
        perror("dtls listen"); <--- "Destination address required"
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

    SSL_accept(ssl);

    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I've added error checks in every nook and cranny I can think of...

What happens is, it loops over `DTLSv1_accept()` fine until a connection is attempted. As soon as the client tries to connect (sends the Client Hello), `DTLSv1_accept()` return -1. A call to `SSL_get_error` gives me 5, which is an `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`.

So I do `perror` and get `Destination address required`...

AFAIK the whole point of `DTLSv1_listen` is to listen for *any* incoming Client Hellos and populate the `BIO_ADDR` with the client's address once the handshake is finished...

I am using this to test the server:

```
openssl s_client -dtls -connect 127.0.0.1:1114
```

I've spent many hours on this. I am about to give up on OpenSSL and try libressl...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. the code is complete, in that it should compile and run if you want to try it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you take a look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627063/clarification-needed-on-openssl-api-in-implementing-dtls-1-2-server)  Would greatly appreciate as you seem to have worked in the very same area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two significant problems in your code sample.

First your code to generate a cookie is not correct. You are supposed to create the
cookie and store it in the location pointed to by `cookie`, and then fill in the length of the cookie in `*cookie_len`. So the code should like this:

```
int generate_cookie(SSL *ssl, unsigned char *cookie, unsigned int *cookie_len)
{
    memcpy(cookie,  "cookie", 6);
    *cookie_len = 6;

    return 1;
}
```

However, the most important error comes later when setting up the SSL object for use. OpenSSL has the concept of a BIO for abstracting the underlying transport layer. In order to do DTLS over UDP you need to use a "dgram" BIO. You do this bit correctly:

```
/* Create BIO */
bio = BIO_new_dgram(sock, BIO_NOCLOSE);

/* Set and activate timeouts */
timeout.tv_sec = 5;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_RECV_TIMEOUT, 0, &timeout);

ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
```

So at this point the SSL object is correctly setup for the `DTLSv1_listen()` call. However you then do this:

```
if(!SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock))
{
    perror("set fd");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The `SSL_set_fd` function is an alternative to the `SSL_set_bio` function. What it does is take the supplied `fd`, wraps it in a "socket" BIO and then calls `SSL_set_bio()` with the result. A socket BIO is primarily useful for standard TLS and can't be used for DTLS. So the effect of the above code is to throw away the dgram BIO that you previously set up.

In my tests, if I made the `generate_cookie` change I suggested above, and removed the `SSL_set_fd` line, it all started to work as expected.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Matt Caswell "In order to do DTLS over UDP you need to use a 'dgram' BIO." Is this really mandatory?  I need to decouple my non-blocking outgoing socket from the BIO. I was thinking of using a Memory BIO on the read and a custom BIO on the write side (writing to the socket) to resolve the issue of MTU exceeded as fragments in memory BIOs get appended and when written to socket could exceed the MTU and get dropped. Is there a solution  other than using a custom BIO? I am only interested in handshake as the application is to get keys for SRTP.

Comment: @asinix it is not mandatory although it is far and away the most common way to do it. You cannot use the standard OpenSSL mem bio because it does not respect the datagram semantics (most importantly packet boundaries and MTU discovery). It would not be too difficult to implement a custom mem bio that did those things - but you don't get it out of the box. You'd have to do it yourself. You talk about MTU in your comment - the standard dgram BIO has the capability to auto discover the MTU - or you can set it explicitly.

Comment: Ah...right just re-read your comment. I realise you said mem bio for the read so MTU discovery is not an issue there...but packet boundaries is.

Comment: @MattCaswell Thank you for your response. So, if I am reading and writing to a non-blocking UDP socket, dgram BIOs for rbio and wbio would be just fine. No need to use any custom BIO?  Is the dgram BIO a recent addition? I see older (2015-2016) DTLS 1.2 implementations using custom  BIO to get around packet boundaries issue.

Comment: The dgram BIO is not a recent addition - its been there for years. So I'm not sure what issues are being worked around in other implementations that you've seen. Note for the auto MTU discovery to work properly you do have to explicitly configure that to happen. Also I mentioned that you can explicitly set the MTU - that *is* a more recent addition and may not have been around in 2015/2016 (I don't recall exactly when that was introduced)

Comment: @MattCaswell I am going to change my code to use dgram BIOs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MattCaswell I have a more detail question but I thought of posting a new question as it is a different issue than the main question posted here. Would appreciate if you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693064/using-openssl-bios-with-non-blocking-sockets-for-dtls-1-2)